# How to manage multiple projects on Docker?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

In our company ~7 projects, each based on Docker. Each project contain base services, like MySQL, Nginx, PHP. Some of projects communicate with other projects. Because of many services on same port, we make new docker host (docker-machine) for each project. From here few problems are coming:

- VirtualBox assign random IP to each Docker host, depends on sequence of executing.
- Hard to switch from project to project, need to set different shell envs all the time. Easy to make mistake.

Well, I'm searching for more enterprise solution to manage many docker machines. Or a some technique that can help me with current situation.

Comment: Why don't you use different ports?

Comment: @constantin-galbenu Because we want to open our websites on local machine with port 80. For example site.com, site2.com instead of site.com:5001, site2.com:5002.

Comment: For this you can have only one machine and a reverse-proxy in front of the services (i.e. HAProxy or Nginx).

Comment: @constantin-galbenu we deploy same docker-compose config to Test and Stage server. It's mean on these servers ports also will be not 80.

Comment: so you put on the two servers a similar reverse proxy

Comment: @constantin-galbenu then how projects should communicate with each other inside a docker host?

Comment: It depends on how you need: internal communication = using the docker service names or external communication = using the FQN of the hosts (site.com or site2.com)

Comment: @constantin-galbenu better to make it in swarm cluster with stacks (projects) or simply with containers (docker-compose)?

Comment: I use docker-compose only for development.

Comment: The idea of my comments so far is that a virtual machine consumes resources and it is best to avoid it if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems last summer.

First, I started to deploy my projects to swarm-cluster as services, instead of clustering several docker VMs. This enabled me to play around services with only the service IDs. It is important that how to separate projects into services, this part may be cumbersome depending on your project.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/deploy-service/

Then, I build my configuration and monitoring software once on swarm-manager and use it. You can use your automation tools on docker-manager to control services.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine consumes resources and it is better to avoid it if is not necessarily. Instead you could deploy the projects in the docker swarm on bare metals.

But because every project has an entry point that needs to be accesible from the outside world (i.e. https://site1.com and https://site2.com) you can't expose the same port (`443` or `80`) for all the frontend services in the same swarm. For this you can use a reverse proxy like HAProxy or Nginx that forwards the requests to the right service based on the hostname. The reverse proxy could be also a service in the swarm. In this situation you should not expose the projects' ports anymore.

A reverse proxy has many other [advantages](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html), like SSL termination (this makes the SSL certificate management a lot easier).

If you add the projects to the same custom network then the services from different projects could communicate securely and directly, using their docker service name and the internal port (i.e. `80`).